# does opencl release all device memory after process termination?

Tags: caching, memory-leaks, opencl

On Linux I used to be sure that whatever resources a process allocates, they are released after process termination. Memory is freed, open file descriptors are closed. No memory is leaked when I loop starting and terminating a process several times.

Recently I've started working with opencl.
I understand that the opencl-compiler keeps compiled kernels in a cache. So when I run a program that uses the same kernels like a previous run (or probably even those from another process running the same kernels) they don't need to be compiled again. I guess that cache is on the device.

From that behaviour I suspect that maybe allocated device-memory might be cached as well (maybe associated with a magic cookie for later reuse or something like that) if it was not released explicitly before termination.

So I pose this question to rule out any such suspicion.

kernels survive in chache => other memory-allocations survive somehow ???

Answer (score 0):

My short answer would be yes based on this tool http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/
I'm investigating a memory leak on my device and I noticed that memory is freed when my process terminates... most of the time. If you have a memory leak like me, it may linger around even after the process is finished.
Another tool that may help is http://www.gremedy.com/download.php
but its really buggy so use it judiciously.